# Interfacing FMC with LCD DBI TYPE B - Intel 8080

Tags: stm32, lcd, stm32h7, fmc

I recently trying to develop on LCD screens, and I saw the [TFT LCD interfacing with the
high-density STM32F10xxx FSMC (AN2790
Application note)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00201397-tft-lcd-interfacing-with-the-highdensity-stm32f10xxx-fsmc-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

and I was going along the way with the Application note just changed everything for my ili9488 and H7 board. In short, it didn't work, and I hoped for a bit of help with analyzing if there is any problem with the timing configuration or address.

Pin A20 for RS. Pin NE1 for CS. FMC clock is 160Mhz.

```
#define LCD_DATA    (volatile uint32_t *)(0x60000000 | 0x0200000)   // Base address of FMC data memory region

#define LCD_COMMAND (volatile uint32_t *)(0x60000000)               // Base address of FMC command memory region
```

and timing configuration:

```
  Timing.AddressSetupTime = 1;

  Timing.AddressHoldTime = 1;

  Timing.DataSetupTime = 32;

  Timing.BusTurnAroundDuration = 0;

  Timing.CLKDivision = 16;

  Timing.DataLatency = 17;

  Timing.AccessMode = FMC_ACCESS_MODE_B;

  /* ExtTiming */

  ExtTiming.AddressSetupTime = 1;

  ExtTiming.AddressHoldTime = 1;

  ExtTiming.DataSetupTime = 5;

  ExtTiming.BusTurnAroundDuration = 0;

  ExtTiming.CLKDivision = 16;

  ExtTiming.DataLatency = 17;

  ExtTiming.AccessMode = FMC_ACCESS_MODE_B;
```

am I wrong?